# How can I use other variable value with for loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops

Here, I want to use other variable value in for loop as I want to get that records.
Here is my code,

```
$chk = $_SESSION['id'];
    $altxt= $_POST['text'];
    for($i=0; $i < sizeof($altxt); $i++)
    {
        if(!empty($altxt[$i]))
        {
            echo "<br>";
            echo "update order_details set process_order='1' tracking_number=$altxt[$i] where id IN(".implode(',',$chk).")";
        }
    }
```

I am getting like this,

```
update order_details set process_order='1' tracking_number=safdf where id IN(8,6)
```

and

I want,

```
update order_details set process_order='1' tracking_number=safdf where id IN(8)
update order_details set process_order='1' tracking_number=safdf where id IN(6)
```

Here, I am getting value of tracking number that is `$altxt[$i]` but I also want to get record of `id` that I coudn't get..

So, how it can be use?

The more code for this,

```
if ($order_list) {
                                    $i = $start +1;
                                    foreach ($order_list as $row) {
                                    ?>
                                        <tr class="border-bottom border-top">
                                            <td class="align-center">
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="id[]" id="id_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" <?php if(in_array($row['id'], $_SESSION['id'])) echo checked; ?>>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="align-center" id="id"><?php echo $i; ?></td>
                                            <td class="align-center"><?php echo $row['order_id']; ?></td>
                                            <td class="align-center"><?php echo $row['order_item_id']; ?></td>
                                            <td class="align-center"><?php echo $row['product_name']; ?></td>
                                            <td class="align-center">
                                                <input type="text" name="text[]" autocomplete="off" id="txtid_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" readonly value="<?php $row['text'] ?>">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    <?php
                                    $i++;
                                }
```

Comment: Is $_POST['text'] an array?

Comment: Yes, @KostasMitsarakis..

Comment: Variable $chk shouldn't be different because it's the session id and it remains the same in the loop.

Comment: You need WHERE id = '$id'; but you should use prepared statements to avoid SQL Injection.

Comment: Yeah you right but $_SESSION['id'] is an array, that's why I am implementing like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 2 foreach loops instead, you should also use `WHERE ID = $id` instead of `WHERE ID IN ( $id )`

Due to your example:

```
$altxt = array( "", "test", "test1","", "", "", "", "", "", "");
$chk = array( "3", "4" );
```

you can try this code with [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php):

```
for($i=0; $i < sizeof($altxt); $i++)
{
    if(!empty($altxt[$i]))
    {
        echo "<br>";
        echo "update order_details set process_order='1' tracking_number=$altxt[$i] where id=".  array_shift( $chk );
    }
}
```

will output this:

```
update order_details set process_order='1' tracking_number=test where id=3
update order_details set process_order='1' tracking_number=test1 where id=4
```

Comment: Thanks @swidmann, but this prints three time update query and as I want one time,
like, 
update order_details set process_order='1' tracking_number=1 where id IN(8)
update order_details set process_order='1' tracking_number=1 where id IN(6)

Comment: Can you provide examples for the content of `$chk` and `$altxt` ?

Comment: thanks, but I need to know what's in the variables, can you add a `var_dump()` of it? or just write it like in the first two lines of my example?

Comment: Thank you so much man..!!
You saved me that i can not explain...
Thanks so much...

Comment: Swidmann: 
Here, if I want to use $chk = array( "3", "7" );
Then array_shift(): could not be used.
Then what is the solution for it?

Comment: just create a new one like `$chk_for_loop = $chk`, this may work